# The first digit matches the last digit in a four-digits number

Tags: regex, regular-language

I'm trying to find numbers that start and end with the same digit and have similar numbers in between the two digits. Here are some examples:

```
7007 1551 3993 5115 9889
```

I tried the following regular expression to identify the first and the last digit. However, no number was selected.

```
^(\d{1})\1$
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`(\d)(\d)\2+\1`

Capture the first and second digits separately, then match them in the reverse order.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YccNOj/8)

Comment: You should somehow wrap your regex with word-border-markers, like `\b(\d)(\d)\2+\1\b`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,

```
^(\d)(\d)\2+\1$
```

might be an option to look into.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dDvfhV/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/dDvfhV/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/dDvfhV/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will match two digit numbers where both digits are the same. You just need to expand it: `(\d)(\d)\2\1`

As well, since the numbers are on the same line, use word boundaries (`\b`) instead of line boundaries (`^` and `$`).

```
\b(\d)(\d)\2\1\b
```

BTW `{1}` is redundant

### [Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DFD47z/1)

Answer (score 1):

Simple JS way.

```js
let a = "7007 1551 3393 5115 9883";
a = a.split(" ");

let ans = [];

a.forEach((val) => {

  let temp = val.split("");
  if (temp && temp[0] === temp[temp.length - 1]) {    
    temp = temp.slice(1,temp.length-1);
  ans.push(temp.slice(0,temp.length).every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] )) ;
  } else {
    ans.push(false);
  }

});

console.log(ans);
```

Regular Expression:

```js
let a = "7007 1551 3393 5115 9883";

a = a.split(" ");

let ans = [];

a.forEach((val) => {

  let reg = /(\d)(\d*)(\d)/gi;
  let match = reg.exec(val);
  if (match && match.length > 3 && match[1] === match[3]) {
    let temp = match[2];
      temp = temp.split("");
      temp = temp.slice(0,temp.length);
     ans.push(temp.every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] )) ;
  } else {
    ans.push(false);
  }

});
console.log(ans);
```